# Get diagnostics information from failed connect from Grafana to InfluxDB

Tags: networking, monitoring, authentication, grafana, database-connection

I've tried to set-up a local [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) instance in a Docker container and I'm trying to connect to my local [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/) that is running on the same machine. I can connect to InfluxDB without any issues, but when I want to setup Grafana to connect to the database, following [these instructions](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/tools/grafana/), I'm getting either an `Error reading InfluxDB` or `InfluxDB Error: Bad Gateway` (when trying Flux and InfluxQL respectively). I've double checked the configuration URL, user-name, password authentication token etc.

My question is: Where can I find some more diagnostics information on this error that helps me to resolve it? The web-interface only shows this non-helpful red banner, but no useful information:

[image]

What I've tried so far:

- Query Language InfluxQL and Flux
- URL (http://localhost:8086) with and without trailing slash
- Ports 8086, 9999 (seen in one of the images in the documentation)
- Basic Auth enabled/disabled
- HTTP Method POST/GET
- Using the connection token as password / using the regular user-password with which I can login to the web-interface

None of these combinations brought me any further to connecting the two things. Any help would be appreciated.

For completeness, I'm setting up the two containers like this:

```
docker run --name influxdb -d -p 8086:8086 quay.io/influxdb/influxdb:v2.0.3 --reporting-disabled
docker exec influxdb influx setup -b reconstruction_watchdog -f -o myorg -u myorg-influx -p myorg-influx -t pVDJA-8Hp_57sPibzqK_16UromM71ywiA3wyxOf0YKQ2bWpTt2pAmLWtHGxXwC39bGqHdh2D6wuZ0pcv1InjFQ== 
docker run -d --name=grafana -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana
```

Comment: Open the developers tool in your browser (F12), go to Network tab and click on `Save & Test`, you'll be able to see the request and the result in the Network tab.